# How do I use createCriteria with nested Associations?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesnt work:

```
Stuff.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
        and {
            eq("status", "READY")
        }
        'owner' {
            'team' {
                eq('name', 'apple team')
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to find stuff where the team name of the owner is `apple team`

Comment: and? what is the problem?

Comment: looks like there's one closing brace too much.
apart from that: please be more precise what you want to achieve. perhaps post some (simplified) domain classes so we can see how the associations are modeled

Comment: oh, hi konstantyn! :-D

Comment: @norganos servus Stephan! )